# Python / linked list / dynamic / overloading

Tags: python, list, dynamic, hyperlink, constructor-overloading

I haven't programmed in a year so I am a little rusty. I really want to incorporate a link list but I am having trouble remembering how the code works, and having to implement it in Python isn't helping.

I only have the Node Class set up so far. Apparently, I cant use overloaded constructors which is annoying...

Basically i want to write a program that prompts a user to enter X number of bucket. Each bucket will have an X amount of different color balls. The user will specify how many balls for each color.

I welcome any help!

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, bucketNumber ,colorONE, colorTWO,
        colorTHREE, colorFOUR, colorFIVE ):
        self.bucket = bucketNumber # index
        self.color1 = colorONE # quantity
        self.color2 = colorTWO # quantity
        self.color3 = colorTHREE # quantity
        self.color4 = colorFOUR # quantity
        self.color5 = colorFIVE # quantity


def printN(bucketNum):
    for i in range(0,bucketNum):
        print(nodes[i].bucket, nodes[i].color1, nodes[i].color2, nodes[i].color3, nodes[i].color4, nodes[i].color5)


colors = []
nodes = []
count = []

bucketNum = int(raw_input("The are 2-5 buckets with 2-5 ball colors. Enter number of Buckets:"))
colorNum = int(raw_input("Enter number of Colors:"))
for i in range(0,colorNum):
    colors.append(raw_input("Enter color: " + str(i+1) ))




for i in range(0,bucketNum):
    for j in range(0,colorNum):

        count.append((raw_input("How many "+ colors[j] +" balls in bucket " + str(i+1))))
    nodes.append( Node(i+1, count[0], count[1], count[2], count[3], count[4]) )
    del count[ 0:len(count) ]




for i in range(0,colorNum):
    print colors[i],
print " "
printN(bucketNum)
```

Comment: And what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to have a question, but note that there is probably no need to use a linked list, unless your list will have many insertions AND be large (because of python `list` memory allocation; and I wouldn't assume that this was a problem until it showed up in profiling), or if you will have many insertions and deletes at the ends of the list.

In that case, python provides [`collections.deque`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.deque) which is a linked sequence.